# Adding Chartist plugin to Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, chartist.js

I am trying to build a project in Angular 5 which has chartist @types and js files of chartist plugins.

The files compile fine in angular 4 but fail to compile or load in Angular 5.
I am confused as to what I am supposed to do.

**Scenario where compilation fails with error `ERROR in error TS5055: Cannot write file '/chartist/chartist-plugin-tooltip.js' because it would overwrite input file`**

In this scenario I directly import files in the components as follows:

```
import * as CLegend from "../../../chartist/chartist.legend";
import * as CPoints from "../../../chartist/chartist.pointlabels";
import * as CFDoughnut from '../../../chartist/chartist.fill-donut';
import * as CTooltip from '../../../chartist/chartist-plugin-tooltip';
```

This works in Angular 4.

**Scenario where compilation succeeds:**

I have added the above mentioned files in `angular-cli.json` under `scripts` key with an array.

```
  "scripts": [
    "../chartist/chartist.legend.js",
    "../chartist/chartist.pointlabels.js",
    "../chartist/chartist.fill-donut.js",
    "../chartist/chartist-plugin-tooltip.js"
  ]
```

I have tried [this guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts), this allows compilation to succeed but I get errors in JS that `Chartist.plugins` is undefined.

I have tried added this in my `typings.d.ts`:

```
interface Chartist {
  plugins? : any
}
```

and this

```
declare module 'ChartistLegend';
declare module 'ChartistPoints';
declare module 'ChartistFDoughnut';
declare module 'ChartistTooltip';
```

I have used both individually but not together.

`ng -v` output:

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
            |___/

Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 6.11.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.0.3
@angular/cli: 1.6.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter: 5.0.3
@angular/material: 5.0.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.3
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Regards

PS: sorry for any typos, my hands are freezing.

EDIT 1: Added angular versions

Comment: I’d make sure that typescript is up to date and build with an —aot flag. I assume that chartist is compatible with angular 5?

Comment: Forgot to mention, chartist is used via `@types/chartist` and build fails with `--prod` flag. `ng serve` first fails then runs normally when I make changes to any file.

Comment: BTW, typescript is 2.4.2.

Answer (score 6):

This took some trial and error as I couldn't find any resources addressing the plugin undefined issue.  In my case adding

```
import * as Chartist from 'chartist';
import 'chartist-plugin-tooltips';
```

resolved the issue.